# @ResponseBody in return type ; 406 error for accept header

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, http-status-code-406

I am using Spring MVC with

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

in my config file.

my contoller method is

```
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<AccountDetails> create(UploadItem uploadItem)   {  
..............
return list;
}
```

Using jre1.7

Still getting HTTP Status 406 error for accept headers..

Comment: this is covered more completely in [Spring JSON request getting 406 (not Acceptable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462202/spring-json-request-getting-406-not-acceptable)

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order for this to work you;ll have to explicitly declare message converters.

Answer (score 0):

You question is pretty sparse on the details, but here's a shot in the dark.

What accept headers are being passed in the request?

What are you expecting to return (XML? JSON?) and how are you expecting that to happen.

If you have JAXB on the classpath and the client specified that it accepts xml then spring will convert it to XML for you.

If you have Jackson on the classpath and the client specified that it accepts JSON then spring will convert it to JSON for you.

Do you satisfy any of those conditions?

[Spring MVC 3: Returning XML through @ResponseBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856298/spring-mvc-3-returning-xml-through-responsebody) may provide more information for you.

Comment: I am expecting the method to return XML. And  jre 1.7 has JAXB implementation. So @ResponseBody should generate the XML. I think i dont need to explicitly declare message converters.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar 406 return code from Spring when the accept header was correct but the JAXB configuration was missing the package name where the marshaled objects reside (the jar had a jaxb.index file in that package but Spring/JAXB was unaware of it.

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxbMarshaller"
    contextPath="colon-separated-list-of-packages" />

This is with Spring 3.20